# Magnetic field - Application of Biot-Savart law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Calculate the magnetic field at the point $P$:

[image]

For me, the contribution of the magnetic field due to the wire where it's inclined is going to be zero, because $\vec{dl} \times \vec{r} = 0$ since the angle is going to be $\pi$ or $0$.

Now, how can I calculate it in the other part of the wire?

Thanks!

Comment: You basically need to integrate with the help of Biot-Savart law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\bf #1}}$

For the tilted segments of the conductor, the contribution to the magnetic field at the point $P$ is zero. For the horizontal segment define the axis as below

[image]

So that

$$
d\vect{l} = dx\hat{\vect{x}} ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ \vect{r} = -r\sin\phi \hat{\vect{x}} + r\cos\phi \hat{\vect{y}}
$$

Therefore

$$
d\vect{l}\times\vect{r} = dx r\cos\phi \hat{\vect{z}} = dx a \hat{\vect{z}} 
$$

Where

$$
r^2 = a^2 + x^2 = a^2 + a^2\tan^2\phi = a^2\sec^2\phi
$$

In this last step I used the fact $x = a \tan\phi$, we can then write

$$
dx = a\sec^2\phi d\phi
$$

Putting everything together

\begin{eqnarray}
\vect{B}_P &=& \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int \frac{d\vect{l}\times \vect{r}}{r^3} \\
&=& \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{-\theta}^{\theta} d\phi\frac{a^2 \sec^2\phi}{(a^2\sec^2\phi)^{3/2}} \hat{\vect{z}}\\
&=& \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi a} \hat{\vect{z}}\int_{-\theta}^{\theta} d\phi \cos\phi \\
&=& \frac{\mu_0\sin\theta}{2\pi a} \hat{\vect{z}}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you for answering. But why isn't $dx = a \text{ tan}(\phi)$?

Comment: @BrunoReis If $x = a \tan \phi$ then $dx = a (d\tan\phi/d\phi)d\phi = a \sec^2\phi d\phi$

Comment: Yeah mate, I got it, but I was asking on why couldn't I define $dx = a \text{ tan}(\phi)$. But moments after my question I realized that is not $dx$ that satisfies this equality, it's $x$, and then we take the differential to find $dx$. Perfect, your answer was very helpful. I got the same answer with a different approach, but I totally agree with yours!